# Class "overloading"

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, overloading

In C++, is there a way to let compiler automatically decide which function you need? You all know that:

```
void F (int i);
void F (char *f);
...
int k = 0;
F(k);

char *f = "0";
F(f);
```

...or via template:

```
template <typename T> 
void F(T i);
...
F(k);
F(f);
```

What is analogy on class level? Is there a way to let compiler decide which class you need?

Comment: What information would the compiler use to deduce the right class to use?

Comment: "You all know this" is a dangerously ignorant assertion. What you have is *overloading*, and not what's commonly termed "polymorphism" at all. *And* on top of that you got the type of `f` wrong.

Comment: what about templates? [here is a refrence](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/templates.html)

Comment: I can't even wrap my head around what problem you're trying to solve. Can you at least post a desired use case pseudo-code example of what you'd like to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

It's not really needed as you have to declare an object of being of a specific class. However, if you have a base class and other classes inheriting from the base class, then you you can use virtual functions and the compiler will pick the correct member function even if you have a pointer or reference to the base class.

It's actually this last piece that is normally called polymorphism, what you are doing with the functions is actually overloading.

Answer (score 1):

No, unlike functions, you cannot have two classes with the same name.

It is possible to parameterize a class with a template parameter, which is somewhat similar, but not the same. Or, more commonly, you can create a *factory* that will create an object of one of a number of types depending on the parameters you pass to it. In the latter case the objects usually extend a common superclass.

Comment: Second this. The factory mechanism gives a runtime-determined object type, but will have to create a polymorphic type and return a pointer (or, less likely, a reference) to it.

The template approach is comparable to the template function, but the instantiated type will be statically determined (i.e. at compile time).